# What is the amount of charge induced in a body if a point charge is brought near it?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, electromagnetic-induction

If a point charge with q charge is brought near a conducting body(especially sphere) how much charge will be induced in the body? Also when will induced charge be equal to inducing charge?
Edit:- I want to know when the conductor is earthed and as well as when it isn't, assuming a metallic body in vacuum or medium.

Comment: Depends on whether your conductor is insulated or grounded (or possibly other boundary conditions)

Comment: I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly the question you are asking is answered in the J.D. Jackson's book "Classical electrodynamics". My following explanation is actually just me following what is written in the book with slight modifications. There, it is answered with the help of the method of image charges. This means that we are removing the sphere and are swapping it for a space with several charges which are positioned such that the field on the "surface" of the space is the same as if the sphere was there.

Let's start with the case of a grounded sphere with the radius $a$. In this instance the outer surface of the sphere will have the potential of $0$. Where inside the spherical region do we need to place a charge and how much of it to create a surface with $\Phi = 0$?

The potential of a charge can be written as
$$
\Phi(\bar{r},\bar{r}') = k\frac{q}{\left|\bar{r} - \bar{r}'\right|},
$$

where $\bar{r}$ is the position of a point in space, and $\bar{r}'$ is the position of the charge.

Let's try creating a spherical surface with $0$ potential with its center at $(0,0,0)$. Due to the symmetry of the problem we can assume that the outside charge and the inner charge are will lie on the same axis. The total potential can then be written as
$$
\Phi(\bar{r}) = k\frac{q_1}{|\bar{r} - \bar{r}'_1|} + k\frac{q_2}{|\bar{r} - \bar{r}'_2|},\tag{1}
$$

where indexes $1$ and $2$ correspond to real and image charges respectively.

Due to the charges being on the same axis and $\bar{r}$ being common for both parts $(1)$ can be rewritten as
$$
\Phi(\bar{r}) = k\frac{q_1}{|\bar{n}r - \bar{n}'r'_1|} + k\frac{q_2}{|\bar{n}r - \bar{n}'r'_2|}.\tag{2}
$$

Now we can factor in the radius value. $(2)$ can then be rewritten as
$$
\left.\Phi(\bar{r})\right|_{r=a} = k\frac{q_1}{|\bar{n}a - \bar{n}'r'_1|} + k\frac{q_2}{|\bar{n}a - \bar{n}'r'_2|} = k\frac{q_1}{a|\bar{n} - \bar{n}'\frac{r'_1}{a}|} + k\frac{q_2}{r'_2|\bar{n}\frac{a}{r_2} - \bar{n}'|}.
$$

It can now be seen that if $\frac{q_1}{a} = -\frac{q_2}{r'_2}$ and $\frac{r'_1}{a} = \frac{a}{r'_2}$, $\left.\Phi(\bar{r})\right|_{r=a} = 0$.

Thus, for the image charge we have
$$
q_2 = -q_1\frac{a}{r'_1}.
$$

As you can see, the induced charge will be equal to the inducing in magnitude if the latter is infinitely close to the surface of the sphere.

The true charge of the sphere will be equal to this image charge. Why? Due to the Gauss' law. It states that
$$
\oint_{S}\bar{E}\cdot d\bar{s} = \frac{Q}{\varepsilon_0}.\tag{3}
$$

The image charge produces the same field outside the sphere as the sphere itself would in this situation. Thus, if the left part of $(3)$ remains the same, so should the total charge in the right part.

If the sphere is insulated, its total charge would be equal to the one it had before the inducing charge appeared. Just rearranged a bit.

If you are interested in the precise distribution of the surface charge on the sphere, I could write it, but it will be just me blatantly copying a paragraph from the book. Better just find it and read it for yourself. It has nice pictures to go with the explanation too.

For other shapes, similar principles can be applied, but, as you can imagine, the complexity of the task increases rapidly for anything other than basic shapes.